# Perl - Apply grep to AoA and get particular element from already returned array

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, grep

I have 2D array and I want to filter by specific index but return another index. I have tried this:

```
print (grep {$_->[0] eq "defuser"} @passwd_file_AoA)[2];
```

But gives me syntax error.

EDIT:

From this array

```
@AoA = ([1,"a","b"],[2,"c","d"]);
```

I want to get
"a"

I have tried following based on bellow suggestions but returns me 1

```
use Data::Dumper; 
@AoA = ([1,"a","b"],[2,"c","d"]);
$a = map { $_->[1] } grep { $_->[0] == 1 } @AoA;
print Dumper $a
```

Comment: `foreach my $row (@AoA) { print $row->[2] if $row->[0] eq "defuser"; }`

Comment: In list context, `map` returns a list of results; you are calling it in scalar context, which simply returns the *number* of results. Simply use a `for` loop like in my previous comment; the intent is much clearer than with `map` and `grep`. You can use `push` to add elements to a new array from inside the loop.

Comment: Also, don't use the variable name `$a` outside of `sort` and *always* `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a brand new array with the values from your array of arrays, you can use `map` and `grep`:

```
my @new_arr = map { $_->[2] } grep { $_->[0] eq "defuser" } @AoA;
```

If you want to print AND make a new array:

```
my @new_arr = map { say $_->[2]; $_->[2] } grep { $_->[0] eq "defuser" } @AoA;
```

(uses `say`, which requires perl 5.10 or greater and `use feature ':5.10'`, but saves you having to type out `\n` every time you print to STDERR)

As ThisSuitIsBlackNot says, printing can be done with

```
for my $a (@AoA) {
    say $_->[2] if $_->[0] eq 'defuser';
}
```